# Can't change anything in Encryption after deleting a vault key

Tags: azure-storage, azure-keyvault

I deleted a key vault that was used in a storage account.

Now if I try to change anything in the Encryption section of the storage (like change the encryption type or using a new key), I am getting:

```
The operation failed because the specified key vault key 'https://dev-certs2.vault.azure.net/keys/<my-previous-key/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' was not found
```

Is there a way to change it without having to create a new storage account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `Soft delete` will be enabled when you create the keyvault, the default retention period is `90 days`, if your keyvault was deleted within 90 days, then you can follow the steps below, if it exceeds 90 days, there seems to be no way to do that without creating a new storage account.(not 100% sure, you may need to contact the azure support)

1.Use powershell to check if the keyvault was in `Removed` state, if there is no output, it means that exceeds 90 days.

```
Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName joyk -Location <the same location with the storage> -InRemovedState
```

[image]

2.Use powrershell to recover the previously deleted keyvault.

```
Undo-AzKeyVaultRemoval -VaultName joyk -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -Location <the same location with the storage>
```

[image]

3.Navigate to the storage account in the portal -> `Encryption` , you will be able to change the `Encryption type` or use a new key. After configuring, then you can delete the keyvault again.

[image]

Comment: That worked! I used `Get-AzKeyVault  -InRemovedState` to get a list of removed keyvaults and get the exact name and location.  Thanks!